# Python HTML data retrieval using htmlParser and soup

Tags: python, html

I am running into a lot of cases where I have to retrieve information from a html page. So I do a HTTP GET on a base url then on HTTP response data which is html page I have to retrieve some information in order to feed that in the next HTTP GET. For example

for a case like this data-->

```
<td class="truncate js-name"><a href="someurl/14?path=Toni&amp;name=abc">abc3</a></td>
```

We use

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    for i in soup.select("td.truncate.js-name > a"):
```

Now I have this

```
<link href="/somePortal/bundles/styles/global?v=xIkoK3DrFy9JG85ulHMbV28CBHIlGEOtWvcFUlIffaY1" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

.....
    
.....

```
   <script src="/somePortal/embedded/scripts/abc?v=7ve7EMIoF-bjIXkqkzhox3OwiYU-m2HsXttE0ATi9-81"></script>
```

....

```
    <script src="/somePortal/embedded/scripts/abc/views?v=2XCWYZkhZOuqO7OBFf8ux7uJDKRAVVCjiMmHzf09OdI1"></script>
```

I need to retrieve the encoded info after ?v=  and use that with each in separate GETs with data before ?v=

Perhaps a dictionary. I can use regular expression, but I am sure it is better with html parser.

Some start with:

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a JSON format , so I used json.loads to retrieve data